# Calculating TOTAL in added input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this small problem. I have been checking out the net to find an answer, but it is mostly for input fields which aren't generated / added.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


/* --- ADD FIELD --- */

    $('.TotalMultiField').each(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.multiFields', this);
    $(".addField", $(this)).click(function(e) {
        $('.multiField:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
    });

/* --- REMOVE FIELD --- */

    $('.multiField .removeField', $wrapper).click(function() {
        if ($('.multiField', $wrapper).length > 1)
            $(this).parent('.multiField').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Above is the Jquery script to add and remove fields. And below is the HTML code. As you see, in the "insert a number" field, the total should appear in the span id="added".

```
<form role="form" action=""" method="">
    <div class="TotalMultiField">
      <div class="multiFields">
        <div class="multiField">
          <input type="date">
<input type="number" class="number" placeholder="Insert a number">
          <button type="button" class="removeField">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    <button type="button" class="addField">Add field</button>
  </div>
  Total:<span id="added"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: So, you would like the sum of all available inputs' values?

Comment: Correct, I know it's possible, I could do it with no-generated fields. But I can't seem to do it with generated / added fields. @LShetty

Comment: Does your add/remove code already work? And post your code in a fiddle.

Comment: Yes, it does indeed. @LShetty

Comment: Seems kind of weird, on fiddle the add/remove doesn't work. Locally it does. I have copied/paste.

Comment: Please create demo that replicates problem. Really not clear what your specific issue even is

Comment: I need the sum of the numbers inserted in the inputs. I know it's a bit un-common. For example, in the 1st input I put 20, and on the 2nd, 30. In the total span should appear 50. @charlietfl

Comment: just loop over the elements and add values together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just noticed you updated that you do indeed want a sum, here is a fiddle with the total calculated on blur and when you remove a row, bind additional events as required (some tidy up is required, but this should get you started):

http://jsfiddle.net/1ggaco1d/4/

The below code does the totaling:

```
function total() {

    var total = 0;
    $(".number").each(function (idx, el) {
        var value = $(el).val();
        if (value !== "") {
            total = total + parseFloat($(el).val());
        }

    });
    $("#added").text(total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/srsu4rne/

You should be able to just count the classes in the div

```
var multiField = $('.multiField').length
$('#added').html(multiField);
```

Comment: Neally, but I need the sum of the numbers inserted in the inputs

Comment: And when do you want it? as and when someone enters a n umber in one of the boxes? or on click of something?

Comment: Oh, ok let me change the fiddle quickly